# Qual a diferença entre usar FileInputStream e FileOutputStream ou Scanner e PrintStream?

Tags: java, input-output

Há alguma grande diferença entre usar essas classes?

Answer (score 10):

## Entrada e Saída em Java

Para entender melhor como funcionam essas classes você deve entender um pouco sobre a API de E/S do Java do pacote `java.io`.

### *Streams*

O básico da API inclui as classes abstratas [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) e [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) que definem a forma como, respectivamente, você lê e grava sequências bytes sem se importar com a fonte ou destino dos dados.

Note que essas classes estabelecem um acesso relativamente de baixo nível, pois trabalham apenas bom bytes.

### *File Streams*

Estendendo as classes básicas, existem diferentes implementações mais específicas, sendo [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) e [`FileOuputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) exemplos que trabalham especificamente com *streams* de bytes em arquivos.

### **Buffered streams**

Ler ou gravar byte a byte não é eficiente, afinal a maioria dos discos e memórias são otimizados para trabalhar com blocos de dados.

Para isso, existem classes como [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) e [`BufferedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) que utilizam o padrão de projetos *decorator* para "decorar" um *stream* e automaticamente gerenciar a leitura e escrita em blocos através de um *buffer* interno.

Isso significa que, numa leitura, a classe vai ler `n` bytes de uma só vez para o *buffer* (sendo `n` o tamanho do *buffer*) mesmo que você efetivamente leia um a um na sua classe. Quando o *buffer* for lido completamente, a classe dispara a leitura do próximo bloco de `n` bytes.

O mesmo vale para gravação. Mesmo que você grave um byte por vez, a implementação *bufferizada* só vai disparar a gravação no disco depois que tiver uma quantidade suficiente de caracteres para encher o *buffer*.

## `PrintStream`

A classe [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) também é uma subclasse de `OutputStream`, assim como `FileOutputStream`.

Ela também permite você decorar qualquer `OutputStream` e lhe dá acesso a vários métodos de mais alto nível. Esse padrão é muito importante para entender essa API.

Então, se você tiver um `OuputStream` qualquer, tal como um `FileOutputStream`, você pode passar esse objeto no construtor do `PrintStream`. Quando você chamar um método de `PrintStream`, por exemplo algum que escreve uma linha formatada de texto, você estará indiretamente gravando bytes no seu `OutputStream` original, mas de forma mais simplificada.

O que confunde um pouco é que `PrintStream` também aceita um arquivo `File` em seu construtor. Porém, note que isso é apenas um facilitador. Se olhar a [implementação](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%2Cjava.lang.String%29), vai ver que ele apenas cria um `FileOutputStream`.

## `Scanner`

Já a classe [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) é um animal diferente. Ela não faz parte do pacote `java.io`.

`Scanner` é uma classe utilitária para interpretar dados simples (primitivos) e delimitados em uma sequência de caracteres. Esses caracteres podem ser lidos de várias fontes, sendo uma delas sequências de bytes, mas pode ser uma simples `String`.

## Não pare por aqui

Existem muitas outras classes na API de Entrada e Saída do Java. Cada uma delas tem um propósito e é importante conhecer algumas delas para tirar o proveito máximo da linguagem.

Além disso, para implementações ainda mais consistentes em com desempenho melhor, considere a API NIO (New Input/Output), que é a forma mais nova e recomendada de acesso a arquivos no Java. Veja a [documentação oficial aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Answer (score 4):

Sim,

- **FileInputStream** e **FileOutputStream**: como os nomes sugerem, são para tratar de arquivos, o primeiro possui métodos para ler um arquivo e o segundo possui métodos para escrever.
- **Scanner** e **PrintStream**: são mais genéricos, podem ser usados em outros streams(não apenas arquivos), o Scanner normalmente é usado para facilitar a entrada de dados do console/terminal:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.nextLine();
```